# Differential equation $\dot{x} = -e^x\cdot \tan(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

This is part of an old exam:

> Given the following differential equation:
>   \begin{align}
> \dot{x} = -e^x \cdot \tan(x), \hspace{1cm} x(t_0) = x_0
> \end{align}
>
> Prove that every solution $x(t)$ with $x(0) = -1$ is strictly monotonously  increasing.

Already proven are the following statements:

> For each $(t_0, x_0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \left]-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right[$ there exists a unique solution and $x(t) = 0$ is the solution fulfilling $x(0) = 0$.

Has anyone tips on how to solve this? Can the already proven facts somehow be used in order to show the statements?

*Edit:* Figures in order to get a feeling for the solution have been drawn. I did not succeed using Separation of variables to compute $x(t)$. If I do not miss something obvious I think it is hard to compute $x(t)$.

Comment: The question is probably meant to be solved *without* computing $x(t)$ explicitly. You have to prove positiveness of the derivative.

Comment: Yeah, I think so as well after I failed to compute it. Nevertheless I have no idea how to solve it ...

Comment: Try to use my hint.

Comment: Alright, so I have to show that $\dot{x} > 0$. $-e^{x}$ will always be negative, so $\tan(x)$ is negative in $\left] -\frac{\pi}{2},0\right[$. Is that a proper starting point?

Comment: Since $-e^x\tan x > 0$ for $x<0$, you have to prove $x(t)$ remains negative for all $t$.  Maybe show that $x(t_0) = 0$ is impossible for your solution.

Comment: Since $-e^x \tan(x) >0$ for $x < 0$ we have that the solution $x(t)$ has to be negative for all $t$ since $\tan(x)$ has to be negative. $x(t) = 0$ would not be possible since that would mean $\dot{x} = 0$.

Comment: Indeed by unicity of solutions to diff eq's, $x=0$ identically is the only solution to your diff eq and $x(s)=0$ for some $s$ (@GEdgar's hint).  But - is the  "strictly increasing" only for $t\ge 0$? Am I missing something? is there any reason for $x(u) =-\pi/2$ not happening for some $u<0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ODE of type
$$\dot x=f(x)\qquad (t,x)\in{\mathbb R}\times\>]a,b[$$
with continuous $f$ has special solutions coming from the zeros $c_k$ $(1\leq k\leq m)$ of $f$. These zeros lead to the $m$ constant solutions $x(t)\equiv c_k$. The graphs of these solutions partition the rectangle ${\mathbb R}\times\>]a,b[$ into horizontal strips. Any other solution stays in a particular of these strips since its graph cannot cross a graph $x(t)\equiv c_k$. In particular any such solution is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing since ${\rm sgn} f(x)$ is constant in each of these strips. For the initial point of your problem this sign is positive. Therefore the solution is strictly increasing as long as it lives. – Similarly, the solution through the initial point $(t_0,x_0):=(0,1)$ would be monotonically decreasing.

Comment: That is a great answer! Thank you! Just to make sure: If it would be $x(0) = 1$ instead of $x(0) = -1$ the solution would be strictely monotonously decreasing, right?

Comment: As "peter a g" notes, in this case $f(t)$ also changes sign when $t=-\pi/2$.  Numerically, it seems this happens at $t \approx -0.053$.  Our solution has a vertical tangent there, but can it match another solution coming from $t<-0.053$?